# Split not working excel VBA

Tags: arrays, string, vba, excel

Input in column `H` from `Row 2`

```
column H
90 million +
550 million +
150 million +
2.1 billion +
110 million +
.
.
.
```

Expected Output in Column `J` from `Row 2`

```
    90 
    550 
    150 
    2.1 
    110 
      .
      .
      .
```

VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertRange()
Dim str As String
Dim Cet
Dim i, j, l As Long
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim wk As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set wk = Sheets("Sheet1")

FinalRow = wk.Range("H900000").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To FinalRow
str = Cells(i, "H").Value
str = Replace(str, " ", "+")
str = Replace(str, "", "+")
str = Replace(str, " ", "+")
Cet = Split(str, "+")

Range("J" & i) = Cet(LBound(Cet))


Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But I am getting wrong Output in Column `J` As follows

```
90 million 
550 million 
150 million 
2.1 billion 
110 million 
.
.
.
```

I believe either of these commands would have replaced the white spaces with the `+` sign

```
str = Replace(str, "", "+")
str = Replace(str, " ", "+")
```

And following line would have an Array wherein LBound value id Cet should be only numbers

```
Cet = Split(str, "+")
```

Where am I wrong ?

> Basically what I want is Cet(0) should be the long or integer number and Cet(1) should be the text billion or million depending on the text in col H for every loop so that I can process this further
>
> So if Column H Row 2 value is 90 million Cet(0)=90 and Cet(1)=million

Comment: Just split on the space and keep the fist one:`Range("J" & i) = split(str, " ")(0)`.  Without all the `Replace`

Comment: `str = Replace(str, "", "+")` is not replacing white space.  It's replacing nothing.  In other words, a replacement isn't happening at all where you think it is. I would add that you probably don't need VBA for this; a simple formula would suffice.

Comment: I don't know your intentions so this may be moot but removing units may be a bad idea given that `2.1` is the largest number here...

Comment: is it always billion or million?

Comment: So after split via space, check first char of the second element for "b" and multiply by 1000?

Comment: And you really want all the whole back into one cell instead of multiple? So you would have five numbers, or more, seperated by carriage returns in one cell?

Comment: @findwindow I don't think you got the question right please review it. Also I am not removing the units I am just saving it on the next element of Cet array

Comment: Oh. Your last edit in yellow makes sense. Everyone here is more able than I in VBA so I let one of them tackle it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems one issue may be that there is not a `space` between the integer and the text string.  Rather there is a `NBSP`.  That being the case, the following should work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ConvertRange()
    Dim Cet
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim wk As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

Set wk = Sheets("Sheet1")
With wk
    FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To FinalRow
        Cet = Split(Replace(.Cells(i, "H"), Chr(160), Space(1)))
        .Range("J" & i) = Cet(0)
        .Range("K" & i) = Cet(1)
    Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it worked thank you may I knw what does NBSP stands for

Comment: @RohanK `NBSP` = Non breaking space; or no break space.  Check it in Wikipedia or Google for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: nice work identifying the non-breaking space from the sample data.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks.  Fortunately, the OP must have copied and pasted the data. Probably the original came from an HTML document or web page.

Answer (score 1):

`Split()` is working fine, you're just not supplying the correct arguments for your `Replace()` method.

> I believe either of these commands would have replaced the white
>   spaces with the + sign
>
> ```
> str = Replace(str, "", "+")
> str = Replace(str, "", "+")
> ```

`""` is just an empty string - you want to replace new line characters for which there are vbConstants:

```
vbCr      '// Carriage Return
vbLf      '// Line Feed
vbCrLf    '// Carriage Return Line Feed
vbNewLine '// Carriage Return Line Feed
```

Or you can use the `Chr()` code:

```
Chr(13)    '// Carriage Return
Chr(10)    '// Line Feed
```

So you need something like:

```
str = Replace(str, vbCrLf, "+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a formula like this in column J not suffice?

```
=LEFT(H2,FIND(" ",H2)-1)
```

It extracts all characters prior to the first space character.

Same approach in VBA like this:

```
Sub test1()
   Dim mystring As String
   Dim newstring As String

   mystring = "1.2 million +" 'hard-coded string
   newstring = Left(mystring, InStr(1, mystring, " ") - 1) 'alteration of my formula suggestion
   MsgBox (newstring) 'see the output

End Sub
```

Comment: No because this is part of a macro that has different aim

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping through the cells, a bulk [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) would be appropriate as long as you discard the fields of information you do not want.

The sample you supplied has a non-breaking space (e.g. `Char(160)`) between the number and the 'million'. This is a common anomaly when copying information from a web page. This should take care of that rogue space character as well as regular (e.g. `Chr(32)`) spaces.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet9")    '<~~ set this worksheet refernce properly
    With Columns(1)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                       ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
                       Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
                       Space:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:=Chr(160), _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 9), Array(3, 9))

    End With
End With
```